# spring boot tomcat J2EE pre-authenticated authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I cannot get the `tomcat` configuration right.

I want to deploy a simple Spring Boot Application on a `Tomcat` with `j2eePreAuth` for `Tomcat` to make the auth.

I read something about a `web.xml` to configure it. They mention to put the security config into a `web.xml` aside the Spring classes. But it did not change anything.

I also tried to change the `web.xml` of `Tomcat` itself with no success.

So my question is: what do i have to configure on `Tomcat` to get this right?

Here is my Security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            // Alle weiteren Pfadsegmente sind für User authentifiziert erreichbar
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .jee()
            // Registrierung eines eigenen Jee PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
                .j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter(j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    /**
     * Um auf die web.xml zu verzichten muss ein ganzer J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter definiert werden. 
     */
    @Bean
    public J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter = new J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter();
        j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());

        J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource = new J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource();
        j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource.setMappableRolesRetriever(simpleMappableAttributesRetriever());

        SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper simpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper = new SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper();
        simpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper.setConvertAttributeToUpperCase(true);
        j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource.setUserRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper(simpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper);

        j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationDetailsSource(j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource);
        return j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter;
    }

    /**
     * Dieser MappableAttributesRetriever liefert eine eigene Liste von JEE Rollen statt der aus einer web.xml.
     */
    @Bean
    public MappableAttributesRetriever simpleMappableAttributesRetriever() {
        SimpleMappableAttributesRetriever simpleMappableAttributesRetriever = new SimpleMappableAttributesRetriever();
        Set<String> roles = new HashSet<String>();
        // Hier müssen die Rollen angegeben werden!
        roles.add(ROLE_PREFIX + "INTERNAL");
        roles.add(ROLE_PREFIX + "MANAGEMENT");
        roles.add(ROLE_PREFIX + "USER");
        simpleMappableAttributesRetriever.setMappableAttributes(roles);
        return simpleMappableAttributesRetriever;
    }

}
```

And a simple `RESt` Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/a")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping("")
    public String index(Principal p) {
        return "logged in as: " + p.getName();
    }

}
```

Comment: I got it to work!

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work!

I added following to `Tomcat`s conf/web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Basic Authentication</web-resource-name>
<!--Here wildcard entry defines authentication is needed for whole app -->
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ROLE_USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <description>Any User</description>
    <role-name>ROLE_USER</role-name>
</security-role>
```